# How in the Heck does visual studio decide on the build order?

Tags: c#, msbuild, visual-studio-2022, .net-4.8

How in the Heck does visual studio decide on the build order?

In theory as far as I know this is how it works.  It looks both at the solution, for solution defined dependencies, these are the ones created by right clicking on a project in the solution explorer and choosing Build\Project Dependencies.  This then lists all the possible related projects in the box under the combobox that has the project you right clicked.

You then tick any projects that need to be built before the project you currently have selected.

Depending on the dependencies you set up you might find that the box is not empty but filled in with a grey colour, if I make Project A dependent on Project B, Project B can no longer by modified to depend on Project A until that dependency is removed, or it may be other projects in the chain of dependencies that are stopping this.

The other way dependencies are defined is that you right click on the <-[ ] References node, choose Add Reference..., and you click on the Projects section, and you have a list of all possible projects, which you can again tick.  However this time the depency is embedded within your project file.  Here you have a very user friendly search box that you can use to find the project you want to build before your current project.

Visual Studio gathers up both of these sets of dependency information and creates the build order for you.

**Edit 1:**
Project A refers to Project B via an Assembly Reference, not a Project References, and it is also listed in the first build dependency mechanism I specified.  In other words the assembly reference appears within the project as

```xml
<Reference Include="A">
      <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

and its also listed in the build dependency dialog mentioned
[image: Illustration of Dependencies]

Note the above is just showing how the dependency was added, to indicate how Project B required Project A to build first.

At least thats whats supposed to happen.  You can take a look at this build order on the build order tab of that first dependencies dialog.

However in my build today despite Project A being further up the list (in other words nearer to the beginning of the build), and Project B, being further down the list, when I look at the build log in the output window (selecting Build Order to see things linearly rather than parelley) - Project A does not get built, it doesn't appear in the list.

We got as far as building Project B which is a C# project, and which depends on Project A (and its defined using the solution method), but it failed to build because it could not see one of the types it required that should be made available when project A finishes (also a C# project) building.

The Configuration manager can affect whether a project builds or not, but when its configured not to build in that configuration then you get the message:

```
nnn->------ Skipped Build: Project: A
```

There was no skipped message, now I did cancel the build before it could go much further because there isn't really any point in continuing as even if the project B, builds it will be too late for Project A which needed it built already in order to use its types.

How is it that Project A which is listed in the build order, and is listed before Project B, yet it did not build.

How am I meant to get the dependencies correct if Visual Studio can decide on a whim not to build something.  I had a check in Configuration Manager, and Project A is ticked for building.

Please help me make sense of this?

Comment: as  long as there aren't any changes, it would noz build it, so ususlly you build the dll in the folder with your main program, so a already build version is present and would only be updated, if there where changes

Comment: Always favor a project reference.  If you pick an assembly then msbuild can't figure out how it got produced and thus won't know how to build it.  And bad things happen when you use Build > Clean.

Comment: _msbuild_ doesn't read any UIs. The settings are saved in the _.csproj_ file for each project - you can open it with _Notepad_ to view the contents. You may consider changing some of the Visual Studio options. For example, Tools => Options... => Projects and Solutions => Build and Run => MSBuild project build output verbosity which will allow you to see more information.

Comment: Visual Studio will add a message at the end of the build with the number of succeeded, failed, up-to-date, and skipped projects. If project A is already up to date, it will not be built and it will be counted as up-to-date. In an incremental build like this, the build order is not changing. Note that `ProjectReference` items effect build order and `Reference` items do not.